# Container div with gradient-background does not allow height: auto

Tags: css, height

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

The outer div("container") doesn't allow height:auto and just hides the complete div with all the content - but I need the outer div to expand since this will be a dynamically filling list later on.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="headline">Headline</div>
  <ul id="u_list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #242424 100%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 82px;
    left: 25px;
}
#headline {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 12px;
    color: white;
}
#u_list {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 12px;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-top: 36px;
}
```

Any ideas what's going on there? :(

Kind regards

Comment: wrong css :
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333
0%, #242424 100%); it should be : 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333
0%, #242424 100%);

Comment: oh, thank you very much - fixed it ;)
my problem got solved by removing position:absolute though^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove position:absolute at #u_list and #headline

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fFsvi

```
#container {
width: 200px;
height: auto;
background: #333333; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #242424 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#333333), color-stop(100%,#242424)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%,#242424 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%,#242424 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%,#242424 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%,#242424 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#333333', endColorstr='#242424',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    position: absolute;
    top: 82px;
    left: 25px;
}
```

I use this tool http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ for gradient

Comment: thx mate, removing position:absolute and adding padding:top/left solved my problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
#container{position:relative;}
```